# How to accomplish floating the tables header when the user scrolls?

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-8, html-table, tableheader

Here are my use-cases:

I want to be able to **float the tables headers** in the page when the user scrolls down in the page. the headers should remain over the table until the user scrolls past the table. This **should work for both for vertical and horizontal scrolling**. It should also work after the user resizes the window and support ie8.

Bonus: 
I also need to be able to do the same thing **inside of a container** that has overflow:scroll and a table inside.

Does anyone know of a plugin that tackles both of these use-cases?

**edit**: I should say that datatables is too big of a plugin for this. It does not support tables with complex headers that I use, and like i said, its 100+ K of code that I would rather not include for this feature.